# Запуск приложения с помощью execlp

Tags: linux, bash, c++, exec

Здравствуйте. Необходимо запустить приложение в gnome-terminal используя функцию execlp. Собственно она запускается вручную из gnome-terminale, если пишу

user@user-laptop:~$ gnome-terminal -e ~/tree/tree

Но на С++ в коде при вызове execlp просто открывается новое окно терминала.

Кусок кода:

---

```
pid_t pid = fork();
switch(pid)
{
 case 0: execlp("gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/user/tree/tree", NULL); exit(1); break;
 case -1: cout << "error!" << endl; break;
 default: wait((int*)0); cout << "I'm a parent!" << endl; cout << "PID = " << pid << endl; break;
}
```

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классическая ошибка использования exec. В качестве первого аргумента, передаваемого запускаемой программе, надо передавать имя самой программы. Например, так

```
execlp("gnome-terminal",  "gnome-terminal",  "-e", "/home/user/tree/tree", NULL);
```

Comment: А расскажите подробнее о каждом аргументе. В чем отличие первого и второго аргументов в данном случае. И в чем отличие будет, если использовать функцию execl

Comment: Первый аргумент данной функции - это имя файла, который должен быть запущен в данном процессе. Далее идут аргументы, которые система передает запускаемой программе. По соглашению, первый аргумент - имя самой программы. На самом деле, это может быть все, что угодно. Подробнее о функциях семейства exec читайте в книгах по Unix/Linux программированию + man 3 exec. Там ничего сложного нет.

Comment: Если в execlp достаточно передать имя файла, и функция будет искать это имя в директориях из переменной окружения PATH, то в execl надо передавать путь к файлу (кажется, можно и относительный).